# Deployment Issue with Spring Boot on Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, github

This is my github repo https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/angularSpringApi which I want to deploy on heroku. The problem is that it is working fine locally but not working on heroku. Can anyone help me out why its not working on heroku?

Heroku link is https://angular-spring-api.herokuapp.com/login . Its giving error that page not found.

This is from the logs of heroku with command heroku logs --tail

```
2017-11-10T14:06:53.418723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=angular-spring-api.herokuapp.com request_id=cd5bf927-f868-4289-a79d-82aa0c97607b fwd=
"182.180.173.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=169ms status=404 bytes=715 protocol=https
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: its not returning jsp page i.e., login page.

Comment: also I have edited the question and included log from heroku